# Can anyone help me because my html page no longer loads images?

Tags: html

Can someone help me because when i create the html page, the browser does not load the images.Should I uninstall the chrome browser?

Comment: The issue is probably not your browser. We will need more details to help you here.

Comment: Right click on your image that doesn't load, in Chrome, and select "**inspect**", then once the inspection window loads move across to the **`console`** tab and see what it says, if it says nothing then refresh the page (F5 key). If it still is blank then go across to the **`network`** tab and then refresh the page and check for `404` network errors on your page load. Explore the console further to discover issues at the Chrome end.

Comment: perhaps it is the fault of the css, less and sass files because, the icon is empty white and no longer colored css
and there is a wheel on the icon.

Comment: can't upload an image?

Answer (score 0):

please check your image path URL link. And please share more info about the issue. Code and other docs.

Comment: This is not really an answer, more like a comment, unfortunately.

Comment: perhaps it is the fault of the css, less and sass files because, the icon is empty white and no longer colored css
and there is a wheel on the icon.

Comment: he didn't post details .

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a folder/file structure.
Please create a Folder named **images**, you don't need to create a folder for images, but please do it!

- Home Folder

  - images

    - image.png
  - index.html

Now, here the basic HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/image.png" alt="myImage">
</body>
</html>
```

Please be sure you use the correct file extension, like .png, or .jpg!
Now you can see the image in your browser!
But please send more information, when it doesn't work!

Have a great day.

Comment: perhaps it is the fault of the css, less and sass files because, the icon is empty white and no longer colored css
and there is a wheel on the icon.